# Get current ULandscapeComponent in C++

Tags: c++, landscape, unreal-engine5

I have a raycast function on my main character and I want to get the Landscape component the character is standing upon. How can I hit it?

Tried this already: `HitResult.GetComponent()` hits the `ULandscapeHeightfieldCollisionComponent`;
`TArray<ULandscapeComponent*>` returns 64 components, I can't get the one it's standing upon;
`ULandscapeComponent* LC = Cast<ULandscapeComponent>(Landscape->GetComponentByClass<ULandscapeComponent>());` returns only one component "LandscapeComponent_0" probably the first one in the array.